# Handle MongoDB scripts in Visual Studio

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio, project-template

I use [NoSQLBooster for MongoDB](https://nosqlbooster.com/) to handle DDL and DCL scripts like scripts for creating database and users, collection validators, initializing some collections and so on; but I use .NET CORE to develop the software and therefore I mainly use the Visual Studio to develop the application.

I remember VS2008 had a project template to handle SQL Server scripts, now **is there a project template in Visual Studio to handle MongoDB data scripts?**

**Update 1:**
I need a project template to:

1. Let me save/categorize my script file
2. Let me execute/debug a single script
3. Let me create execution configurations and execute them
4. Gives Intellisense while developing

Comment: Define "handle". You mean that when opening a file containing MongoDB queries, you want a button that says "Run" which, when clicked, executes it on a selected database?

Comment: Thanks  @CodeCaster. My needs are exactly like what I have in other code/development projects. I'll update the question to better describe what I need as a project template.

Answer (score 0):

A [Visual Studio project template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019) is basically just a zip file containing a couple of files that will be copied for any project you create using that template.

Visual Studio has no inherent MongoDB support (though VS Code does). If you want to run MongoDB queries from within Visual Studio, you'll have to install an extension that does so, for example [Mongo DB Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pachi.MongoDBToolsv10) (which I'm not affiliated with nor have I ever used it).

So I doubt you actually want a project template. You can organize files in any project type.

Comment: I tried to download that extension; but their website wasn’t working and I got some server errors and gave up. My goal is not only organizing scripts, I need run/debug abilities plus some other features I’ve included in the update1 to my question. :)

Comment: Yes, but that has nothing to do with a project template. You need to find an extension that can do that, or use VSCode: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/azure/mongodb